# How to open the add media dialogue it in a certain state / tab?

Tags: javascript, media-library, media-modal, thickbox

I created a customized `wp_view similar` to embed (see [wp-includes/js/mce-view.js, l. 868](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.4/src/wp-includes/js/mce-view.js)).
I also have my own tab in the "add media" dialog. Naturally I want the edit button of my `wp_view` opening the add media dialog with the right tab.

Currently I use this:

```
edit: function(text, update) {
    tb_show('Some headline', 'media-upload.php?tab=mytab&someparams='+somevalues+'&amp;TB_iframe=true');
}
```

I works like a charm, **but**

- the edit and delete buttons keep staying in foreground, even before the thickbox.
- in the [codex is written](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/ThickBox):

  > As of WordPress 3.5, the "Media" button for WordPress's post editor no longer utilizes ThickBox, but instead uses a custom Javascript modal.

So I really would prefer to use this custom modal.  Is anyone able to explain me how to open the add media dialog it in a certain state (means tab)?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to open the modal to the create gallery section:

```
var options = {
frame: 'post',
       state: 'gallery',
       title: wp.media.view.l10n.createGalleryTitle,
       multiple: true
};

var frame = wp.media.editor.open(null,options)
```

If you want something else, I suggest you search through the core js [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src//wp-includes/js/media-views.js#L5163) to change the Library ID as appropriate for the section you need.